# $\mathbb E(X)=\sum \mathbb E(X\mid Y)\mathbb P(Y=n)$ ¿why?

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation, conditional-probability

Let $\langle X, Y\rangle$ be a random vector such that $X$ has finite expected value and $Y$ is discrete with values $​​0.1, \cdots $ such that $\mathbb P (Y = n)> 0$ for $n = 0.1, \cdots$ Show that

$$\mathbb E(X)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \mathbb E(X\mid Y)\mathbb P(Y=n)$$ Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, note that $E[X]=E[E[X|Y]]$ by the tower property of conditional expectations.

Note that

$$
E[X|Y=n] = \frac{\int {\bf 1}_{(Y=n)}X(\omega)dP(\omega)}{\int {\bf 1}_{(Y=n)}dP(\omega)}= \frac{\int {\bf 1}_{(Y=n)}X(\omega)dP(\omega)}{P(Y=n)}
$$
which is a numerical value for each $n$ and represents the average of $X$ over the set $(Y=n)$.

And, $E[X|Y]$ is a random variable. We can define a version (P-a.e. equal) of $E[X|Y]$ by 
$$
E[X|Y](\omega) = E[X|Y=n] \qquad for \qquad \omega\in (Y=n)
$$

Thus, 
$$
E[X|Y](\omega) =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} E[X|Y=n] {\bf 1}_{(Y=n)}(\omega)
$$

Now,
\begin{eqnarray*}
E[X] 
&=&
E[E[X|Y]]\\
&=&
E\left[\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} E[X|Y=n] {\bf 1}_{(Y=n)}\right]\\
&=&
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} E[X|Y=n] E\left[{\bf 1}_{(Y=n)}\right]\\
&=&
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} E[X|Y=n] P(Y=n)
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 0):

It because [Low of total expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation)
$$\mathbb E(X)=\mathbb  E(\mathbb E(X\mid Y))=\sum_y \mathbb E(X\mid Y=y) \mathbb P(Y=y).$$